# How can I embed a Custom Field Value in a link?

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, custom-fields

I'm trying to link posts from WordPress to an associated post on Tumblr. I have the Tumblr id set as the value for a custom field in each WordPress post.

Here's what makes sense to me, but the link isn't capturing or outputting the value:

```
<h3><a href="http://xxx.tumblr.com/post/<?php $key="mykey"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, tumblr_id, true); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'hapcam' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```

Is there a problem with the above code that anyone can see? Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated, thanks!

Also, I'm using the Ajax Load More plugin to load the posts to the page, not sure if that's why...

Answer (score 0):

The meta key should be a string. You're not using `$key` so I'd remove that to avoid confusion.

Change this:

```
<?php $key="mykey"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, tumblr_id, true); ?>
```

To:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tumblr_id', true ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that makes sense, but unfortunately still isn't working. I wonder if it's because I'm using ajax to embed the post onto the page. Ajax Load More plugin, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I realize what the problem is, because I'm using a function to load the posts to the page, `global $post;` needs to be declared within the loop.

Also, as @Nathan Dawson pointed out the meta key needed to declared as a string.